# Python redis-py hget operation slow on high concurrency

Tags: python, performance, redis, load-testing, gevent

I've a redis server hosted on AWS with several Hashes (around 1700000 keys), each having single key value pair. They are in the following format:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[10]> HGETALL "date:20170420:len:3"
1) "prices"
2) "{\"price\": \"500.84\", \"tax\": \"10.00\", \"total\": \"510.84\"}"
```

I've an API which reads the value from these hashsets, and collates them and gives out the response. Here's what the code looks like:

```
def fetch_prices(dates):
    import time
    import math
    st = time.time()
    # Total keys: len(date) * len(l)
    dates = {"date:{date}:len:{l}".format(date=d) for d in dates for l in [1, 2, 3]}

    pipe = r.pipeline()
    stc = time.time()
    timer_logger.info("Total HGET operation: %s", len(dates))
    for d in dates:
        pipe.hget(d, 'prices')
    etc = time.time()
    timer_logger.info("for loop on hotel total time: %s ms", math.ceil((etc - stc) * (10 ** 5)) / (10 ** 2))

    stc = time.time()
    values = pipe.execute()
    etc = time.time()
    timer_logger.info("hgets total time: %s ms", math.ceil((etc - stc) * (10 ** 5)) / (10 ** 2))
    stc = time.time()
    return_value = [json.loads(v, object_hook=price_hook) for v in values if v]
    return return_value
```

Now, when I hit this API using Apache Bench at 200 concurrency, I see that total time `hget` takes is gradually increasing:

```
ab -n 200 -c 200 "http://api.hitting.cache/"
```

Here's the log of the total time printed for `hget` operation:

```
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 17.81 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 291.11 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 108.25 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 171.45 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 343.58 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 175.16 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 241.48 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 425.97 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 238.87 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 310.88 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 297.65 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 218.19 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 352.3 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 379.52 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 400.81 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 304.29 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 459.14 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 474.69 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 378.81 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 537.63 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 537.2 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 455.07 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 605.66 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 602.16 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 534.19 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 588.35 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 702.08 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 696.57 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 652.01 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 754.78 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 455.07 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 605.66 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 602.16 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 534.19 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 588.35 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 702.08 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 696.57 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 652.01 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 754.78 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 495.6 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 718.97 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 431.86 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 485.82 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 791.71 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 538.0 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 850.11 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 611.74 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 903.57 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 664.5 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 952.11 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 529.03 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 629.71 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 678.35 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 743.31 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 804.98 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 831.75 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:07] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 857.5 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 939.2 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1264.54 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 876.55 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 990.76 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1292.21 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1035.62 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1340.49 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1105.4 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1378.29 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1140.46 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1416.63 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1109.07 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1102.94 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1457.5 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 919.83 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1487.42 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 880.02 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1535.06 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 904.95 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1574.73 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 973.43 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1607.64 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 957.17 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1648.63 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1020.83 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1714.63 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1751.34 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1789.32 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1816.73 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1862.82 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1899.62 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1935.82 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1971.54 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2006.62 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:08] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2036.07 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2074.11 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2112.46 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2153.43 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2186.09 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2225.63 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2263.8 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2297.19 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2344.4 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 2380.6 ms
[22/Apr/2017 07:05:09] INFO [timer.caching:106] hgets total time: 1087.45 ms
```

These numbers are with total **46-50 HGET** operations per API hit.
As you can see towards the bottom half, the time is reaching 2 seconds, that looks like too much for an 50 HGET operations.

I'm testing this on Python version 2.7, redis-py==2.10.5, with hiredis-parser==0.2.0. I'm running this on gunicorn server with gevent workers.

The API is hosted on AWS t2.medium (2 CPU, 8 GB memory) machine. And cache.m4.large (2 CPU, 6.4 GB memory) redis instance on AWS Elastic Cache.

I'm running the apache bench test from another AWS machine, hosted in the same availability zone. Any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong here?

Here's the profiler numbers for one of the API call (This one has surprised me). Took this number while the system was already at load of 200 concurrency:

```
         980279 function calls (933994 primitive calls) in 5.772 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       45    0.000    0.000  123.777    2.751 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py:534(switch)
       45    0.005    0.000  123.776    2.751 {method 'switch' of 'greenlet.greenlet' objects}
     45/1    0.001    0.000    5.839    5.839 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py:489(wrapper)
     45/1    0.001    0.000    5.839    5.839 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py:57(wrapped_view)
     44/1    0.001    0.000    5.830    5.830 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py:64(view)
     44/1    0.001    0.000    5.830    5.830 /usr/src/app/pricing/api/api.py:87(dispatch)
     44/1    0.002    0.000    5.829    5.829 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/hooks/component_djangorestframework.py:4(_nr_wrapper_APIView_dispatch_)
     44/1    0.006    0.000    5.825    5.825 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py:428(dispatch)
     44/1    0.058    0.001    5.825    5.825 /usr/src/app/pricing/api/pricing_api.py:80(get)
     44/1    0.008    0.000    5.769    5.769 /usr/src/app/timer/caching.py:169(fetch_prices)
     44/1    0.007    0.000    5.769    5.769 /usr/src/app/timer/caching.py:82(fetch_prices)
     44/1    0.000    0.000    5.750    5.750 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py:2605(execute)
     44/1    0.019    0.000    5.750    5.750 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py:2492(_execute_transaction)
  2112/48    0.018    0.000    5.750    0.120 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py:2582(parse_response)
  2112/48    0.004    0.000    5.750    0.120 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py:583(parse_response)
  2112/48    0.003    0.000    5.750    0.120 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py:574(read_response)
  2112/48    0.012    0.000    5.750    0.120 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py:329(read_response)
     44/1    0.001    0.000    5.750    5.750 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py:420(recv_into)
     43/1    0.000    0.000    5.750    5.750 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py:286(_wait)
     46/1    0.002    0.000    5.750    5.750 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py:343(wait)
     43/1    0.001    0.000    5.749    5.749 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py:320(run)
     43/1    0.022    0.001    5.749    5.749 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py:30(handle)
     43/1    0.000    0.000    5.735    5.735 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py:157(handle_request)
     43/1    0.009    0.000    5.735    5.735 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py:87(handle_request)
     86/2    0.004    0.000    5.731    2.866 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py:1172(_nr_wsgi_application_wrapper_)
     86/2    0.001    0.000    5.729    2.864 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py:703(__iter__)
     86/2    0.002    0.000    5.729    2.864 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py:1079(__call__)
     43/1    0.001    0.000    5.722    5.722 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py:162(__call__)
     43/1    0.008    0.000    5.722    5.722 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py:94(get_response)
      745    0.008    0.000    2.930    0.004 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1267(_log)
      659    0.003    0.000    2.902    0.004 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1157(info)
      745    0.002    0.000    2.803    0.004 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1288(handle)
      745    0.006    0.000    2.797    0.004 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:1320(callHandlers)
     2593    0.017    0.000    2.792    0.001 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:746(handle)
     2593    0.037    0.000    2.694    0.001 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py:849(emit)
     2593    2.446    0.001    2.446    0.001 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
       43    0.000    0.000    0.588    0.014 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py:149(render)
       43    0.000    0.000    0.587    0.014 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py:39(rendered_content)
       43    0.359    0.008    0.585    0.014 /usr/src/app/pricing/api/api.py:21(render)
```

Is gevent the culprit? And what's that {method 'write' of 'file' objects} could be doing for 2.5 seconds?

I've seen the latency, which looks fine:

```
$ redis-cli -h host -p 6379 --latency
min: 0, max: 10, avg: 0.67 (23382 samples)
```

Comment: Did you ever get any insight on this?